# Erro de conversão implícita de tipos

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'CursoCAvancado.Cliente' to 'string' C:\curso\CursoCAvancado\CursoCAvancado\Form1.cs 47  31  CursoCAvancado

Segue a classe

```
namespace CursoCAvancado
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Conta conta;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Sacar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                double valor = Convert.ToDouble(txtValorSaque.Text);
                this.conta.Saca(valor);
                if (valor < 100)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Saque efetuado com sucesso" + this.conta.Saldo);
                }
            }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.conta = new Conta();
            this.conta.Titular = new Cliente("everson");
            this.conta.Numero = 1;
            this.conta.Deposita(100);

            txtNumero.Text = Convert.ToString(this.conta.Numero);
            txtSaldo.Text = Convert.ToString(this.conta.Saldo);
            txtTitular.Text = this.conta.Titular;

        }
     }
}
classe conta
 class Conta
    {
        public int Numero { get; set; }
        public double Saldo { get; set; }
        public Cliente Titular { get; set; }

        public void Saca(double valor) 
        {
            this.Saldo -= valor;
        }
        public void Deposita(double valor) 
        {
            this.Saldo += valor;
        }
        public void Transfere(double valor, Conta destino) 
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Classe cliente

```
public class Cliente
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Cliente(string nome) 
    {
        this.Nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Everson, tente escrever um título descritivo e explicar melhor seu problema e seu código. É só [edit] a pergunta. Se tiver interesse, tem um guia: [ask].

Comment: `txtTitular.Text = this.conta.Titular;`

Comment: Eu tenho feito mais ainda assim aparece a mensagem de erro, bfavaretto

Comment: O que quero dizer é que o erro está nessa linha. Titular é um cliente, txtTitular.Text é texto. Acho que você quer this.conta.Titular.Nome

Comment: obrigado @bfavaretto deu certo era isso mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

O erro cita a linha 47 do arquivo. Acredito que seja esta:

```
txtTitular.Text = this.conta.Titular;
```

Se `this.conta.Titular` é um `Cliente`, você não pode atribuir direto ao valor de um campo de texto, que deve ser uma string. Para preencher com o nome do titular, faltou pegar a propriedade adequada do seu `Cliente`:

```
txtTitular.Text = this.conta.Titular.Nome;
```